# How to store the element inside anchor tag in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using table and the element inside the table are added dynamically with the `JSON` data. The table data consists of `Id` and other things. I had put id inside the anchor tag so that it gets navigated to another page which shows all the data of that `Id`. I  want to show the data of only selected `Id`. So I want to set the element inside the anchor tag to a variable ... is there any way to achieve this ?

```
<a href="other_page.html">link Label<a>
```

Now I want to store this "link Label" into a variable in JavaScript or AngularJS is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data` attribute for this. for example

```
<a href="other_page.html" data-id="3" id="click">link Label<a>
```

and in you javascript :

```
<scrtipt>
  document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    alert(this.getAttribute("data-id"));
});
</script>
```

Hope it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="jsonObject.id" href="other_page.html" onClick="clickFunction">link label</a>
```

You can set anchor id with that particular id. Then on click function you can send event object and get that particular ID.

JS code

```
function clickFunction(event){
console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do!

You can get the text inside tags by calling `.innerHTML` of the element. In your case this would mean something like this:

```
<a href="other_page.html" id="tagid">link Label<a>
```

You need an `id` for the tag and then in JavaScript

```
var value = document.getElementById("tagid").innerHTML;
```